# Column width not the same in seaborn graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am working on the kaggle's titanic dataset and I'm using a seaborn Facetgrid histplot plot. I am wondering why the column width is not the same in the last column graph.

```py
a = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_all, row='Survived',col='Embarked',height=5, aspect=1)
a.map(sns.histplot, 'Fare',bins=10)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're looking for the `binwidth` parameter, not `bins`, notice it's also different in the bottom middle one.

Comment: You are right. My intention is to bin the Fare into 10 groups as well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Easiest would be to calculate the binwidth as `(max - min)/10`.